# Bootstrap tooltip not display on hover or click in ipad

Tags: jquery, html

i am using fontawesome icon to display book star rating  .If i click that icon i want to display tooltip it is working fine in desktop and mobile browser but it is not showing the tooltip only in ipad.

html:

```
<i data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-user-26" title="title"></i>
```

js:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
});
```

what is problem why it is not showing .. help me please..
Thanks..

Comment: If your project on live, share your live project link

Comment: Try put ur code in codepen or fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3zdadh1L/5/  .. open the link in ipad and test but it is working in desktop browser

Comment: Your fiddle is incorrect, since you've not loaded jquery before loading bootstrap etc... Check this version: https://jsfiddle.net/3zdadh1L/6/ ... The tooltip in your example is just the native HTML one, not Bootstraps tooltip! ...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3zdadh1L/8/ check this version on ipad for normal desktop it's working charm but in ipad not working..

Comment: @mathi it is an issue just check out this link https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15935